# How to multiply two matrices to get an array?

Tags: r, matrix, multiplication

I have two matrices:

```
A =
|1 0 1|
|0 1 1|
|1 1 1|
|1 1 1|

B =
|1 1|
|0 1|
|0 0|
|1 1|
```

How can I multiply these two matrices in R without using a `for` loop
to get a 3 dimensional array C[2,4,3] that C[1,,]= A * B[,1] and C[2,,]= A * B[,2]

```
C[1,,]=
|1 0 1|
|0 0 0|
|0 0 0|
|1 1 1|

C[2,,]=
|1 0 1|
|0 1 1|
|0 0 0|
|1 1 1|
```

Comment: it would be helpful to know *why* you want to avoid loops.  Efficiency?  Elegance?  Homework problem (seems unlikely)?

Comment: This part of code should already be inside an other loop and B and A are not small in size. So I want to make it efficient.

Comment: well, the *most* efficient way would prob. be to write it in Rcpp.  I tried but failed (so far) to do it with a Kronecker product + `array()` + `aperm()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New version based on making matching dimension matrices:

```
array(
  A[,rep(seq_len(ncol(A)),ncol(B))] * B[,rep(seq_len(ncol(B)), each=ncol(A))],
  dim=c(nrow(A),ncol(A),ncol(B))
)
```

---

Technically still a loop, but so sue me:

```
A <- matrix(c(1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),nrow=4)
B <- matrix(c(1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1),nrow=4)

mapply(`*`, list(A), split(B,col(B)), SIMPLIFY="array")

#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    0    1
#[2,]    0    0    0
#[3,]    0    0    0
#[4,]    1    1    1
#
#, , 2
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    0    1
#[2,]    0    1    1
#[3,]    0    0    0
#[4,]    1    1    1
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you said it is still a loop and it takes a lot of time in my code

Comment: @user2079550 - try the new option as it avoids looping.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
n <- ncol(A)
m <- ncol(B)
k <- nrow(A)
B1 <- c(apply(B,MARGIN=2,rep,n))
aperm(array(B1*c(A),c(k,n,m)),
      c(3,1,2))
```

I could benchmark against @thelatemail's answer, but I'm not sure it's worth doing with such a small example, and I can't be bothered to construct a larger one ...

Comment: Thank You, I will check that and will put some feedbacks here.